# PostgreSQL database causing loss of datetime-values

Tags: postgresql, datetime

I have a PostgreSQL database containing a table with several 'timestamp with timezone' fields.
I have a tool (DBSync) that I want to use to transfer the contents of this table to another server/database.

When I transfer the data to a MSSQL server all datetime values are replaced with '1753-01-01'. When I transfer the data to a PostgreSQL database all datetime values are replaced with '0001-01-01'.
The smallest possible date for those systems.

Now i recreate the source-table (including contents) in a different database on the same PostgreSQL server. The only difference: the sourcetable is in a different database. Same server, same routing. Only ports are different.
User is different but in each database I have the same rights.

How can it be that the database is responsible for an apparant different interpretation of the data? Do PostgreSQL databases have database-specific settings that can cause such behaviour? What database-settings can/should I check?

To be clear, I am not looking for another way to transfer data. I have several available. The thing that I am trying to understand is: how can it be that, if an application reads datetime info from **table A** in **database Y** on **server X**, it gives me the the wrong date while when reading the same table from **database Z** on **server X** will give me the data as it should be.

Comment: You say you "Transfer" them.. what does that mean? Copy data out onto the clipboard, paste into excel, email to your coworker, copy and paste back out into an access database with a link table to the sql server? (Totally kidding, but some clarification here would be helpful to explain the steps you are taking to move this data to each system).

Comment: You are right, I will update the question

Comment: If you can *see* correct timestamps in the source databases, I'd suspect DBSync or source db data types. I think there's more than one product called DBSync. It might help to edit your question, and link to the DBSync you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the cause is probably the difference in server-version. One is a Postgres 9 (works ok), the other is a Postgres 10 (does not work okay).
They are different instances on the same machine. Somehow I missed that (blush).

With transferring I meant that I am reading records from a sourcedatabase (Postgresql) and inserting them in a targetdatabase (mssql 2017).
This is done through the application, I am not sure what drivers it is using.

I wil work with the people who made the application.
For those wondering: it is this application: **https://dbconvert.com/mssql/postgresql/**

When a solution is found I will update this answer with the found solution.

Comment: The term "Postgres 9" covers **7** different major versions